# Form randomly not submitting values to database

Tags: php, html, mysql

I guess I can't post more than 2 links because I'm new so I'll put the links on pastebin. http://pastebin.com/2kab4LND

Basically, I wrote a form to submit values to my database. These values being Nickname, Title, Date, and Content (which is basically where they write something)
Anyways, a couple hours ago this was working perfectly. No matter what amount of text the content value was, it submitted to the database.

The first picture shows the database working as intended.

However, now when I try to use the form to submit values identical to that one, it will simply not show up with no errors. The second picture shows roughly how big I could get the content before it would simply not show up. Everything else works, such as nickname and title, it's just the content that doesn't work once it exceeds the limit I guess.

I didn't change any of my code, so I'll show that after I show you my mysql tables.

The third picture shows my tables. I didn't change anything about them.
The tables looked like that when they worked perfectly.

Here's my form code. I removed some stuff so it's slightly easier to read, but that's as good as it'll get. This is the code that worked before, and I didn't change a bit of it, so I'm not sure if there would be any errors that would cause this to happen. Now I'll show you what it connects to. Sorry it's really messy.

```
<?php

 echo "<form id='submit-form' name='submit-form' action='".setDreams($conn)."' method='POST'>
  <input type='hidden' name='dreamid' value=''>
  <input type='hidden' name='date' value='".date('Y-m-d H:i:s')."'>
  <div id='title'>
    <textarea type='text' name='dreamtitle' value='title' id='title_textarea' placeholder='Write the title of your dream here. (Max 40 characters)' method='POST' rows='1' style='margin-left: 10px' style='z-index: 1'></textarea>
  </div>
  <div id='dream_editor'>
   <textarea type='text' name='thedream' value='dream' id='dream_textarea' placeholder='Describe your dream here (Must be at least 250 characters)'  method='POST' rows='8' style='margin-left: 10px' style='z-index: 1'></textarea>
  </div>
    <div id='desired_nickname'>
    <textarea type='text' method='POST' type='nickname' name='dreamnickname' value='' id='nickname_textarea' placeholder='Write your desired nickname' rows='1' style='margin-left: 10px' style='z-index: 1'></textarea>
    </div>
    <button id='submitDreamButton' style='margin-bottom: 10px' name='dreamSubmit' type='submit'></button>
    <button id='cancelButton' style='margin-bottom: 10px' href='index.php'></button>

  </form>";
  ?>
```

This is the function that works off of the form. Anyways, as I already said this is the code that worked, until it stopped working after me having not changed it. I looked over it many times and haven't found any errors.

```
 <?php
function setDreams($conn) {
    if (isset($_POST['dreamSubmit'])) {
        $uid = $_POST['dreamid'];
        $date = $_POST['date'];
        $dreamtitle = $_POST['dreamtitle'];
        $thedream = $_POST['thedream'];
        $nickname = $_POST['dreamnickname'];

        $sql = "INSERT INTO dreams (dreamid, nickname, date, content, title) VALUES ('$uid','$nickname','$date','$thedream','$dreamtitle')";
        $result = $conn->query($sql);
    }
}
```

This is stressing me out because I know it just worked and I'm so confused why it's not working now. I hope this post wasn't too hard to read and I hope you understand the problem :)

thanks in advance

Comment: add all code here, as code not images

Comment: Sorry yeah I'll do that

Comment: action has to be  filename\URI (there is NO way this code ever worked as shown)

Comment: The action calls the function I showed at the bottom of my post.

Comment: no it dosent work that wway

Comment: Change here action='".setDreams($conn)."' To any file name where you want post data.

Comment: @jertyu: for the form action ur code calls setDreams function which doesn't return any value, the action value should be appropriate URI. So if you check the source of ur webpage in browser action won't have any value.

Answer (score 0):

Your `action` attribute must be in URL format.

```
<form id='submit-form' name='submit-form' action='process.php' method='POST'>
    <input type='hidden' name='dreamid' value=''>
    <input type='hidden' name='date' value='".date('Y-m-d H:i:s')."'>
           <div id='title'>
        <textarea type='text' name='dreamtitle' value='title' id='title_textarea' placeholder='Write the title of your dream here. (Max 40 characters)' method='POST' rows='1' style='margin-left: 10px' style='z-index: 1'></textarea>
    </div>
    <div id='dream_editor'>
        <textarea type='text' name='thedream' value='dream' id='dream_textarea' placeholder='Describe your dream here (Must be at least 250 characters)'  method='POST' rows='8' style='margin-left: 10px' style='z-index: 1'></textarea>
    </div>
    <div id='desired_nickname'>
        <textarea type='text' method='POST' type='nickname' name='dreamnickname' value='' id='nickname_textarea' placeholder='Write your desired nickname' rows='1' style='margin-left: 10px' style='z-index: 1'></textarea>
    </div>
    <button id='submitDreamButton' style='margin-bottom: 10px' name='dreamSubmit' type='submit'></button>
    <!-- Your submit button must have the value attribute otherwise, isset($_POST['dreamSubmit']) means your button doesn't have a value -->
    <button id='submitDreamButton' style='margin-bottom: 10px' name='dreamSubmit' value="Submit" type='submit'></button>
    <button id='cancelButton' style='margin-bottom: 10px' href='index.php'></button>

</form>
```

process.php

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['dreamSubmit'])) {
    setDreams($conn);
}

function setDreams($conn) {
    $uid = $_POST['dreamid'];
    $date = $_POST['date'];
    $dreamtitle = $_POST['dreamtitle'];
    $thedream = $_POST['thedream'];
    $nickname = $_POST['dreamnickname'];

    $sql = "INSERT INTO dreams (dreamid, nickname, date, content, title) VALUES ('$uid','$nickname','$date','$thedream','$dreamtitle')";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);
}
```

Comment: obligatory: if you use raw user input as variables into a db query you will get hacked.

Comment: I have a file called dreams.inc.php that contains the function I showed at the bottom of my post. I used "include 'dreams.inc.php' and then called it in my form. Does that not work? Because it was worked a couple hours ago.

Comment: @jertyu no way that worked, simply can't be the case. perhaps the code was not in a function at the time?

Comment: I know it worked because I saw it work right after I finished coding it. I'll try what he said though.

Comment: @thewbmstr to be honest I tried your code and it still didn't work.

Comment: @dagon i don't know how I can be wrong about it working if I saw it working for hours.

Comment: It has the same problem that my OP is about. Everything works fine except for if the content is too long then it doesn't work. I know that my action isn't the problem because everything else works.

Comment: what are the db field types and sizes?